# Selenium select strings seperated by tag

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Suppose I have the following HTML code

```
<tag1>
 "hello"
 <tag2></tag2>
 "world"
</tag1>
```

Then `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"tag1").text` outputs the string `"helloworld"`. How can I get the strings `"hello"` and `"world"` separately or at least get a string `"hello world"` seperated by whitespace?

Comment: You may get downvotes if your question looks like you didn't attempt to solve the problem yourself. A [mcve] always helps.

Answer (score 2):

`<tag1>` has 3 child nodes, the text node "hello", the empty `<tag2/>`, and the "world" text node. When you call `.text` on a node, it just combines the text representations of all child nodes. You don't get a space between "hello" and "world" because whitespace does not matter in XML / HTML.

You can iterate over `tag1`'s child nodes instead of calling `.text`, and then decide what to do with the children. If you know it's only 1 level deep, you can call `.text` on each child node and concatenate the results with separators like spaces. If this gets deeper than just one level of child nodes, you can recurse the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert has already said there are 3 child nodes of `tag1`. You can get all of them with JavaScript code

```
script = "return document.getElementsByTagName('tag1')[0].childNodes"
nodes = driver.execute_script(script)
```

Since `tag2` is not a text node Selenium "knows" how to handle it, so it will be returned as `WebElement` instance... Two others are text nodes and Selenium "doesn't know" how to handle them, so they will be returned as dictionaries (something similar to what `script` code returns originally in JavaScript).

To get required output and ignore `tag2` you can do:

```
text = ' '.join([node['textContent'].strip() for node in nodes if isinstance(node, dict)])
```

The output of `print(text)` should be `'hello world'`